# Pass Image to WebAPI from MVC contoller so that it's available in HttpContext.Current.Request.Files

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2, httpclient, multipartform-data

I have created a webApi which expect form-data. I am passing both image and data to the WebAPI. When I pass the parameters using PostMan i can recieve data inside model and file is avialable inside HttpContext.Current.Request.Files.

Now i want to pass same data and image to webapi though MVC contoller. Data am able to get in my api method but getting file proving to be a difficult task.
This is my APi method

```
  [Route("Profile/EditUserProfileAsync")]
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> EditUserProfile(UserProfile userProfile)
    {
        try
        {

            var Identity = (ClaimsPrincipal)Thread.CurrentPrincipal;
            int UserId = Convert.ToInt32(Identity.Claims.Where(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.Sid).Select(c => c.Value).SingleOrDefault());
            if (UserId == 0)
            {
                return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, "User Not Found!");
            }

            userProfile.UserId = UserId;
            HttpRequestMessage request = this.Request;
            if (!request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
            {
                throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType);
            }


            var Result = await _userprofile.EditUserProfile(userProfile);
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, Result);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            await _log.logError(new ErrorLog() { CreatedDate = DateTime.Now, CustomMessage = "Error in EditUserProfile API", ErrorMessage = ex.Message, ModuleName = "UserProfile", StackTrace = ex.StackTrace });
            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

This is the method that is being called by the api to save data

```
 public async Task<MethodResult> EditUserProfile(UserProfile userProfile)
    {
        MethodResult methodResult = new MethodResult();
        bool profileComplete = true;
        try
        {

            if (userProfile.ImagePath == null && HttpContext.Current.Request.Files.Count == 0)
            {
                return new MethodResult() { Success = false, Message = "Profile Image is required !!" };
            }

              // some code here
           }
          catch(Exception ex)
          {
             // log error
          }
       }
```

here files count is always comming as zero in the EditUserProfile method in webapi

This the MVC controller code

```
  [Authorize]
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<JsonResult> SaveUserProfileDetails(UserProfile userProfile)
    {
        string Result = "true";
        try
        {
             var identity = (ClaimsPrincipal)Thread.CurrentPrincipal;
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Remove("Authorization");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", identity.FindFirst("AcessToken").Value);


            MultipartFormDataContent form = new MultipartFormDataContent();
            form.Add(new StringContent(userProfile.FirstName), "FirstName");
            form.Add(new StringContent(userProfile.UserId.ToString()), "UserId");
            form.Add(new StringContent(userProfile.LastName), "LastName");
            form.Add(new StringContent(userProfile.Designation), "Designation");
            form.Add(new StringContent(userProfile.Gender.ToString()), "Gender");
            form.Add(new StringContent(userProfile.City), "City");
            form.Add(new StringContent(userProfile.Country), "Country");
            form.Add(new StringContent(userProfile.DateOfBirth), "DateOfBirth");
            form.Add(new StringContent(userProfile.Specialties), "Specialties");
            if (Request.Files.Count > 0)
            {
                MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
                Request.InputStream.CopyTo(ms);
                byte[] data = ms.ToArray();
                ByteArrayContent fileContent = new ByteArrayContent(data);
                fileContent.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment") { Name = "file"};

                form.Add(fileContent);
            }
            else
            {
                form.Add(new StringContent(userProfile.ImagePath), "ImagePath");
            }





            var resp = await client.PostAsync(Constant.ApiBaseUri + "Profile/EditUserProfileAsync", form);
            if (resp.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var result = await resp.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                MethodResultVM<string> methodResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MethodResultVM<string>>(result);
                Result = methodResult.Message;
            }
            else
            {
                Result = "false";

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Result = "false";
        }

        return Json(Result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

with this i am relieving Input stream in header. But i don't want that  as android and ios applications are already using the same api and i don't want to modify the api.

Please guide me what can be done to recieve IMAGE in httpcontext in web api controller from httpclient object in mvc controller.

Comment: currently r u getting this message => `Profile Image is required !!` right?

Comment: and where this => `_userprofile` has been located in same project web api project or any other repository project?

Comment: Yes coz in mvc controller as file is available so   form.Add(fileContent) get executed so userProfile.ImagePath is null and HttpContext.Current.Request.Files.Count is 0.
_userprofile  is in same solution another project

Comment: try to count your file in web api controller instead of  `EditUserProfile`. we have to watch is there file comes or not?

Comment: File won't be available there. I am passing the file as attachment in header which will be available as input stream there. this is the problem , i need to know how can i pass file from mvc controller so that it is available in Request object in webapi controller

Comment: it means your mvc controller not passing files to web api controller

Comment: did u get any data inside => `byte[] data = ms.ToArray();`? in mvc controller

Comment: yes. In mvc controller everything works . From mvc i am passing it as MultipartFormDataContent. As i mentioned earlier that i can access this file as input stream in webapi controller .

Comment: make sure file count is not 0 on controller side....

Comment: @TAHASULTANTEMURI which controller side ?? in mvc controller i have file and in webapi controller i don't which is the question that i have asked , how will i get file here in Request object.

Comment: @user1063760, are you trying to send multiple files from mvc to web api or single file?

Comment: @user1063760,  try to replace your code in mvc controller => `if (Request.Files.Count > 0)
            {
                var file = Request.Files[0];
                byte[] fileBytes = new byte[file.InputStream.Length + 1];
                file.InputStream.Read(fileBytes, 0, fileBytes.Length);
                var fileContent = new ByteArrayContent(fileBytes);
                fileContent.Headers.ContentDisposition = new System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment") { FileName = file.FileName };
                form.Add(fileContent);
            }` and let me know

Comment: @ershoaib single file.

Comment: @user1063760, did u try my above last commented code?

Comment: @ershoaib there is no point trying your code. you are basically doing the same thing. file will not be available in response object.